# Difference between withStateAtLeast and whenStateAtLeast lifeCycle extension methods

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle, android-jetpack

There are two similar extension method in androidX `lifecycle-ktx` package with slightly different signature. [`withStateAtLeast`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#whenstateatleast) and [`whenStateAtLeast`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/package-summary#whenstateatleast). I read the doc but couldn't understand the difference in their behavior. An example on when we should use which one, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source code, [whenStateAtLeast](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/lifecycle/lifecycle-runtime-ktx/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/PausingDispatcher.kt#153) runs the given block when the lifecycle is at least in the required state **and suspends the block if the lifecycle moves to lesser state while block is running**.

At the same time [withStateAtLeast](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/lifecycle/lifecycle-runtime-ktx/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/WithLifecycleState.kt#148) just waits for the lifecycle to be at least in the required state and runs the block. So it guarantees that the lifecycle state meets the requirement at the time it starts the block, but if the block suspends, by the time it's resumed, the lifecycle can be in lesser state or even destroyed.

So in general `withStateAtLeast` is a good choice if you need to run a block when lifecycle reaches the state (e.g. user entered the screen) and finish its execution in any case, even if the user leaves the screen before the execution finished. `whenStateAtLeast` in its turn is useful when the block works with UI, it guarantees, that each time it resumes execution, the lifecycle is in proper state, so you can access UI safely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This could be another question, but I I'm not mistaken, we should be able to use `whenStarted` for collecting flows in UI. But Google [documentation](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#stateflow) handles that manually by defining a `job` and canceling that in `onStop`.

Comment: I'd say yes, most of the time when working with UI it's better to use `whenStateAtLeast` or its counterparts - `whenStarted`, `whenStarted`, since most of the time we should access UI when it's visible only.